# Dúvida sobre Inherit e atributo Float em CSS

Tags: css

Tenho uma atividade para fazer sobre CSS que envolve Inherit e atributo Float. A instrução indica o seguinte:

> Construa o seguinte layout contendo três div’s , em formato de coluna,
> a primeira contendo o texto “coluna 1” em branco e fundo preto , a
> segunda contendo o texto “coluna 2” em branco e fundo verde e a
> terceira contendo o texto “coluna três” em branco e fundo cinza,
> utilize uma div como “pai”, todas terão o mesmo tamanho que deve ser
> de 150 pixels de altura de 150 pixels de largura: [imagem de exemplo anexada]

[image: Imagem anexada no exercício, como deveria ficar a página - divs "colunas" um ao do outro com as dimensões indicadas (150px por 150px)]

Beleza, tudo certo até a parte do div "pai". Quando os 3 divs do começo do exercício foram atribuídos, em CSS, com o elemento Float, funcionaram perfeitamente como indica o exemplo. Porém, quando colocado esses divs dentro do div "pai" e feito com que todos herdem as dimensões dele, o Float não funciona mais.

Código HTML e CSS:

```css
#pai {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#um {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
#dois {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
#tres {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercicio2.css">
            <title>Exercício 2</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "pai">
                <div id = "um">
                    Coluna 1
                </div>
                <div id = "dois">
                    Coluna 2
                </div>
                <div id = "tres">
                    Coluna 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Queria saber qual seria a solução para isso dentro dos limites dados pelo exercício?

Comment: Bom dia, Acho que o enunciado poderia ser mais claro, mas pelo que entendi aquele tamanho se aplica apenas as div's filhas. Se a div pai não for maior as div's filhas teriam que ficar sobrepostas, o que acho que não faz muito sentido. Espero que ajude

Comment: Realmente, a questão está bem mal escrita. Na hora de resolver pensei que faria sentido, já que "utilize uma div como “pai”, todas terão o mesmo tamanho que deve ser de 150 pixels de altura de 150 pixels de largura", mas aí colocando essa div pai ela não teria nenhuma função além de estar ali. Mudei o código, tirei o id da div pai e coloquei as mesmas medidas em cada uma das divs no css (que é o que deu certo antes). É com certeza um erro nessa relação mesmo que você disse.